# Create object instance from assembly using AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a class library ClassLibrary1.dll in c:\MyDll\ClassLibrary1.dll with this

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Class 1 Library ");
    }
}
```

Using AppDomain how would i create a instance for the class Class1 and execute the method "Run" in .net 2.0
Note: I do not want to use Assembly.LoadFile

Comment: Why do you not want to use Assembly.LoadFile? That is the method you should use.

Comment: i need to unload this assembly from memory after execution

Answer (score 1):

This page discusses creating app domains, loading assemblies and types into that app domain, and then closing the app domain:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk22e11a.aspx